# Highcharts(column type) remove the padding between the first rect and upper boundary

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/ovbzL6fo/1/

```
enter code here
```

I want to remove the padding. Hope the first blue rect start from the top of the container.

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2eLxsot9/1/

Comment: Another thing you should be able to do is to set column groupPadding and pointPadding to 0: http://jsfiddle.net/ovbzL6fo/2/